# Saturação de foreign keys?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Após um longo tempo com banco de dados nao relacional decidi voltar e me deparei com uma situação estranha. Minha aplicação é um simples chat onde esse chat tem sub salas.

Fiz uma pequena demonstração:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso do id do usuário na sala para saber em qual sala do chat ele esta e também preciso do usuário na mensagem para saber quem enviou.

Tenho quase certeza que esta está errado, é realmente necessário essas foreign keys? ou poderia retira-las deixando somente o campo controlado pela aplicação?

@edit

Ignore os erros de modelagem, foi feita somente para demonstração.

Comment: FKs são opcionais, você usa caso queira deixar com o banco a garantia de integridade relacional; mas se não houver um motivo para não criar as FKs, o padrão é criá-las (elas não costumam atrapalhar em nada). Agora, a tua modelagem parece esquisita: id do usuário na sala? Só tem um usuário em cada sala??

Comment: Verdade... houve um erro ali, vou editar avisando do erro. Com todas essas FK's o oracle data modeler vira um bagunça da impressão que esta errado por isso da pergunta. Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Ok, estendi o comentário numa resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Foreign Keys* na base de dados são opcionais, você as cria caso queira deixar com o servidor de banco de dados a garantia de integridade relacional; por exemplo: o banco não deixará criar um registro com uma *foreign key* apontando para um registro inexistente, nem deixará excluir um registro para o qual existam outros registros relacionados via FK.

Quando o banco de dados é utilizado por uma única aplicação e a própria aplicação vai se encarregar destas validações, as FKs no banco podem ser dispensadas.

Há que se considerar o custo de fazer estas verificações de integridade relacional no aplicativo ou deixar que o banco as faça - provavelmente o banco fará com muito mais performance pois além de ser especialista no assunto, ele está mais perto dos dados e tem recursos que vão além de simples queries SQL para fazê-lo.

Portanto, se não houver motivo para não criar as FKs, o padrão é criá-las; afinal a garantia de integridade relacional é uma das grandes propostas dos servidores de bancos de dados relacionais.

Quanto à **saturação de foreign keys**, há que se observar primeiro se a modelagem está correta, mas também pode acontecer de ela estar correta e o excesso de FKs causar alguns problemas.

Há servidores de bancos de dados (SGBDs) que possuem limites de FKs para uma tabela, sendo que entre eles há os que bloqueiam a criação de uma nova FK para uma tabela já saturada e há outros que permitem a criação mas depois podem apresentar problemas ao tentar excluir ou alterar registros para os quais existam muitas FKs. Isso pode ser um problema em sistemas com milhares de tabelas e tabelas com muitas colunas.

Para evitar estes tipos de problemas em grandes bases de dados, há que se agrupar as informações em tabelas menores em vez de se desenhar tabelas gigantescas.

**Update:** de qualquer modo os SGBDs estão sempre em aprimoramento e diminuindo suas limitações.

Por exemplo, o [SQL Server 2012 tinha um limite recomendado de 253 FKs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432(v=sql.110).aspx). Eu vi tabelas com mais de 300 FKs *incoming* funcionando em SQL Server 2005 mas era impossível modificar ou excluir registros em alguns servidores. [Atualmente a documentação alega suporte a 253 FKs *outgoing* e 10.000 *incoming*!](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx#Engine).

<sub>Não encontrei documentação do limite de FK por tabela no Oracle.</sub>